# Presenting Arima results - Use of Stargazer (or other equivalent package)?

Tags: knitr, stargazer, arima

I currently have several ARIMA models in R which I'm looking to present formally within a paper.

I'm just wondering if a tool exists that will allow me to illustrate these results, without having to manually extract this data?

Unless I'm mistaken, I understand stargazer does accommodate arima variations, but not the "Arima" code found within the forecast package. When I have tried to use the latter, I have received an error message telling me it is an "unrecognised object type".

Is there anything else that can be done?

Separately, for other types of diagnostic outputs (e.g. Augmented Dickey-Fuller tests, etc), are there other ways kable, etc, can be used to present these results?

Thanks in advance for any help!